# Can this be done in SQL? Calculating Max ports useds

Tags: sql

I have a database that has the times that physical ports are used on a server.  The each server has up to 48 communications channels that get allocated as needed.

When a transaction occurs, a record is stored showing the port #, when the activity began, and when it ended.

What I need is to find out at any given time how many ports are in use for Each server in the system.  (I need this to plan for expansion.)

My original solution was to run the a query, collect the data, save it to the HD, and run a script to calculate the Port usage, and import that into Excel to graph the results.

I want to know if there is a way to do the whole calculation in SQL so I can setup a Excel to run the query and update automatically.

One other reason why I wanted to do this in SQL was Excel barfs on the amount data I'm trying to import.  So running a VB script isn't practical either.  I need to pare the data down before it enters Excel.

Comment: 'for Each server in the system' Is there anything in the table that indicates which server the activity was logged from?

Answer (score 0):

If I am correctly understanding the question, something like this should work:

```
select count(al.portNumber) as activePortCount
from @ActivityLog al
where al.startTime <= @queryTime and al.endTime > @queryTime
```

You mentioned needing to get this count for each server in your system.  If you had a column that specified the server in some way, something like this would do that:

```
select count(al.portNumber) as activePortCount, al.serverId
from @ActivityLog al
where al.startTime <= @queryTime and al.endTime > @queryTime
group by al.serverId
```

In both examples @queryTime is the time for which you are trying to determine the count of active ports.  ActivityLog is a table modeled after the structure you mention in the question, though in the second example I added a column that indicates which server the activity was on.  Both examples assume that a port can only be active 'once' at a specific unit of time.  I am not a networking guy, so if this is not the case, the queries will have to be slightly modified.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been on here much.  No time with typeically with my job, even when I need the info I can get here.

Comment: I need the # of ports used over time.  So it looks like your query is just giving me a "snapshot?"  Is this correct?
i.e. I need ports used at 10,10:05,10:10,10:15, etc, etc..